# SQL user permissions in 2 databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario where I need to allow a user in one database access to objects in another database on the SAME SQL server.

**SQL SERVER SETUP:**
I have an SQL Server 2008 Express instance running.

Within that instance I have the following :

**2 databases :**
DATABASE1
DATABASE2

**2 logins :**
ADMIN1
ADMIN2

DATABASE1 has a user (*USER1*) created on ADMIN1 and has permissions on SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT and GRANT EXECUTE on stored procedures in DATABASE1

DATABASE2 has a user (*USER2*) created on ADMIN2 and has permissions on SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT and GRANT EXECUTE on stored procedures in DATABASE2

**QUESTION :**
What I require is to allow 'USER1' SELECT/EXECUTE permission to tables and stored procedures in DATABASE2

I have tried a few snippets of SQL from a few posts but I have no idea how to write the SQL.
I also tried doing it manually in the way of ticking checkboxes for permissions by right clicking the user and logins in Management Studio but
I need SQL to execute in my scripts.

**THE REASON FOR MY QUESTION**
I have tables in DATABASE1 and DATABASE2 which are related but obviously we cant create Foreign Key constraints across different databases.
The best way we have thought to handle the relationship between the 2 tables is to create a stored procedure in DATABASE1 to query the 
relevant table in DATABASE2 and return a result.

Apologies for not being able to post any examples as I cannot find any examples out there through my searches which match the scenario I have described above.
If I can give any further information please let me know.

Many thanks
Kev

Comment: Just another idea.......that I've seen when "crossing databases".  Idea 1.  Create a view in Database1 that references Database2.  I would put it under a newly defined schema name.  So...querying database 1 (to see data in db 2), you'd have "Select A,B,C from OtherDatabasesSchema.vwCounty         ........   Idea2, using synonyms in your code in db1, and the synonym can point to objects in database 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your user is defined at the instance level, you can grant them whatever rights they need in each database.  Create your users under the master, and then add them as users of each database granting them whatever rights are needed per the specific DB.

EDITED with more detail (based on comments):

First, you need to create a Database Login.  This is a login that can then be added as a user to one or more databases on your instance.

Details Here (including SQL syntax):  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx

Second, you need to provision the user in the database (Database1, Database2, etc...).  You will want to have these users added identically to each of these product databases that gets installed.  As long as the user is there, you will be able to query across the various DBs on your instance.

Details Here (Including SQL):  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response MystikSpiral. The thing is, DATABASE1 is created first, DATABASE2 is for a different product and will only be created if Product 2 is purchased. DATABASE1 is already on a number of customers servers and therefor the users are created already. Is there a way that if the Users are assigned to the databases already, that I can edit their permissions where they exist currently ? without having to re-create the users under the master db?

Comment: You did not mention the presence of the databases is variable, that changes things considerably.  Do you have control of the setup of each database?  If you do, configure them with the correct rights before the DB is deployed.

Comment: In essence there could be a DATABASE3 and a DATABASE4 which could be created in the future. ie: not all databases are created at the same time and therefor don't know about each other. So I need the USER1 in DATABASE1 to be able to ' Adapt' in a sense to be able to read any other databases should they come along in the future. The thing is, USER1 exists inside DATABASE1. Hope that provides a little more insight. thanks

Comment: You need to have a user created above the singular database, that can span across all these entities you may or may not have.  Until you have that in place, you are not going to be able to get this to work.  I may be missing something in translation here, but that is how it appears based on what you have shared.

Comment: thanks mystik-  would  you be able  to  offer a so lution in  terms of which system database to put  them  under if  any? I dont  know. how  to implement  the solution  to.my issue so.I.do  need  help  in  understanding  how I. can  go  about allowing the  requirements based on my example.  if u can give  me an  example with any sql  required I will test itv out and  Mark  your answer as accepted. many  thanks..  kev